# How to configure drupal webistes in aeigr 2.0 with SNI?

Tags: aegir

Original configuration, supposed to work, but it didn't

In /var/aegir/config/server_master/apache/vhost.d/cc-prod.local

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>

    DocumentRoot /var/aegir/platforms/production/drupal-7.27 

    ServerName cc-prod.local
    SetEnv db_type  mysql
    SetEnv db_name  ccprodlocal
    SetEnv db_user  ccprodlocal
    SetEnv db_passwd  12345
    SetEnv db_host  localhost
    SetEnv db_port  3306
    # Enable SSL handling.

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /var/aegir/config/server_master/ssl.d/cc-prod.local/openssl.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/aegir/config/server_master/ssl.d/cc-prod.local/openssl.key


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/files/(.*)$ /sites/cc-prod.local/files/$1 [L]
  RewriteCond /var/aegir/platforms/production/drupal-7.27/sites/cc-prod.local/files/robots.txt -f
  RewriteRule ^/robots.txt /sites/cc-prod.local/files/robots.txt [L]
</IfModule>

  # Extra configuration from modules:

      # Error handler for Drupal > 4.6.7
      <Directory ~ "sites/.*/files">
        <Files *>
          SetHandler This_is_a_Drupal_security_line_do_not_remove
        </Files>
        Options None
        Options +FollowSymLinks

        # If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
          php_flag engine off
        </IfModule>
      </Directory>

    # Prevent direct reading of files in the private dir.
    # This is for Drupal7 compatibility, which would normally drop
    # a .htaccess in those directories, but we explicitly ignore those
    <Directory "/var/aegir/platforms/production/drupal-7.27/sites/cc-prod.local/private/" >
      <Files *>
        SetHandler This_is_a_Drupal_security_line_do_not_remove
      </Files>
      Deny from all
      Options None
      Options +FollowSymLinks

      # If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
      <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_flag engine off
      </IfModule>
    </Directory>

  </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

  DocumentRoot /var/aegir/platforms/production/drupal-7.27
  ServerName cc-prod.local
  SetEnv db_type  mysql
  SetEnv db_name  ccprodlocal
  SetEnv db_user  ccprodlocal
  SetEnv db_passwd  12345
  SetEnv db_host  localhost
  SetEnv db_port  3306


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/files/(.*)$ /sites/cc-prod.local/files/$1 [L]
  RewriteCond /var/aegir/platforms/production/drupal-7.27/sites/cc-prod.local/files/robots.txt -f
  RewriteRule ^/robots.txt /sites/cc-prod.local/files/robots.txt [L]
</IfModule>

# Extra configuration from modules:

    # Error handler for Drupal > 4.6.7
    <Directory ~ "sites/.*/files">
      <Files *>
        SetHandler This_is_a_Drupal_security_line_do_not_remove
      </Files>
      Options None
      Options +FollowSymLinks

      # If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
      <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_flag engine off
      </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    # Prevent direct reading of files in the private dir.
    # This is for Drupal7 compatibility, which would normally drop
    # a .htaccess in those directories, but we explicitly ignore those
    <Directory "/var/aegir/platforms/production/drupal-7.27/sites/cc-prod.local/private/" >
      <Files *>
        SetHandler This_is_a_Drupal_security_line_do_not_remove
      </Files>
      Deny from all
      Options None
      Options +FollowSymLinks

      # If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
      <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_flag engine off
      </IfModule>
    </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

I pull the cc-prod.local 443 setting, and put it into /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf, I have the following

```
 #This is a simple html site and it is working

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
ServerName your_ssl.local 
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/testme/your_ssl
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apache.key
</VirtualHost>


#Also, in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf, I have the following

# This is a drupal site and I got error 
# An error occurred during a connection to cc-prod.local. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. (Error code: 
# ssl_error_rx_record_too_long) 

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
 DocumentRoot /var/aegir/platforms/production/drupal-7.27 

    ServerName cc-prod.local
    SetEnv db_type  mysql
    SetEnv db_name  ccprodlocal
    SetEnv db_user  ccprodlocal
    SetEnv db_passwd  12345
    SetEnv db_host  localhost
    SetEnv db_port  3306
    # Enable SSL handling.

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /var/aegir/config/server_master/ssl.d/cc-prod.local/openssl.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/aegir/config/server_master/ssl.d/cc-prod.local/openssl.key


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/files/(.*)$ /sites/cc-prod.local/files/$1 [L]
  RewriteCond /var/aegir/platforms/production/drupal-7.27/sites/cc-prod.local/files/robots.txt -f
  RewriteRule ^/robots.txt /sites/cc-prod.local/files/robots.txt [L]
</IfModule>

  # Extra configuration from modules:

      # Error handler for Drupal > 4.6.7
      <Directory ~ "sites/.*/files">
        <Files *>
          SetHandler This_is_a_Drupal_security_line_do_not_remove
        </Files>
        Options None
        Options +FollowSymLinks

        # If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
          php_flag engine off
        </IfModule>
      </Directory>

    # Prevent direct reading of files in the private dir.
    # This is for Drupal7 compatibility, which would normally drop
    # a .htaccess in those directories, but we explicitly ignore those
    <Directory "/var/aegir/platforms/production/drupal-7.27/sites/cc-prod.local/private/" >
      <Files *>
        SetHandler This_is_a_Drupal_security_line_do_not_remove
      </Files>
      Deny from all
      Options None
      Options +FollowSymLinks

      # If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
      <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_flag engine off
      </IfModule>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The error I got after moving cc-prod.local 443 setting to /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

Access https://cc-prod.local, gets error

> "An error occurred during a connection to cc-prod.local. SSL received
>   a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. (Error code:
>   ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)"

How do I fix it?

Comment: Aegir 2.0 does not really support SNI, 3.0 does.

Comment: Ok. I upgraded it to aegir 3.0. For example, I enabled SSL on one website. I found that I need to copy the SSL config to ssl.conf in Centos, in order to work. That is not ideal, as the SSL config is generated. Is it better way to do it?